# Set Quantiy dropdown in Magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How do I change the Quantity text input box to a dropdown on configurable products?

I've got this piece of code in my /catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml file

```
<select name="qty" id="qty" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?php// echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>">
<?php $i = 1 ; ?>
<?php 
while( $i < 5) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?>"><?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?></option>
    <?php $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

It works fine.but In my scenario for ex:
**Boots:**

Size 6 - 3 pairs

Size 7 - 2 pairs

Size 8 - 1 pair

Size 9 - 4 pairs

When I select "Size 6," I'd like the Quantity dropdown to be 1-3. If I select size 9, it should go up to 4.
How to get qty in this template file.
If anyon knows please expain me.

Comment: Can you provide an image that have your select box within option

Comment: updated my post @Nero

Comment: So you want when you choose size 6, the drop down will take the option like : 1,2,3. And when choose size 7, it will be changed to 1,2?

Comment: Yes ...........

Comment: It can do by Jquery. I will reply soon

Comment: Can you explain how can you get the qty each size? and how can you get list of size?

Answer (score 1):

Its working for me...

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">     
   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" type="Xxx\Qty\Block\Option" />      
</config>
```

**Option.php**

```
<?php

namespace Xxx\Qty\Block;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;

class Option extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $_stockRegistry;

    public function __construct(StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry, \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder, \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string, \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig, \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat, \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository, \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $urlEncoder, $jsonEncoder, $string, $productHelper, $productTypeConfig, $localeFormat, $customerSession, $productRepository, $priceCurrency, $data);
    }

    public function getStockMaximumQty()
    {
        $id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
        $stockItem = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItem($id);
        $stockQty = $stockItem->getQty();
        return $stockQty;
    }

}
```

**addtocart.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php  $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php  $qty = $block->getStockMaximumQty(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
            <select name="qty" id="qty" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" 
                   class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>">

                <?php if($qty > 4){?>
                   <?php $i = 1 ; 

                     while( $i <= 4) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?>"><?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?></option>
                        <?php $i++; ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                         <?php } else { 
                               $i = 1 ; ?>
                          <?php    while( $i <= $qty ) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?>"><?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * $i; ?></option>
                        <?php $i++; ?>
                    <?php }?>
                     <?php }?>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php else : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to change the code, I will provide the logic of code:

```
select name="select1" id="select1">
  //Get the list of size, with each size, set the value is its qty
  <option value="<?php echo $qty[$i]?>"><?php echo $size[$i]?></option>
  ...
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
    //Get list of qty depend each size
    //for ($count = 1; $count < $qty[0]; $count++)
    <option value="<?php echo $count ?>"><?php echo $count ?></option>
</select>

JS code:

$("#select1").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  $('#select2').empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < id; i++) {
      $('#select2').append('<option>'+i+'</option>');
  }
});
```

Hope it will help!